# Some troubles with Java ArrayList.contains()

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm pretty new to Java and I have a problem and I can't seem to find the answer to it.
I'm trying to find out if the language I pass exists in my list.

```
String lang = "fr, de, gb, nl, se, es";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] languages = lang.split(",");
result = Arrays.asList(languages);
if (result.contains("de")) {
    return true;
} else {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

And this returns false, i can't understand why.

Comment: You should try to debug your code

Comment: try " de" as that is your string not just de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are splitting on just the comma, therefore your array contains strings with spaces in front. Use this regex instead to split:

```
lang.split("\\s*,\\s*")
```

On a side note, you don't need these three lines:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] languages = lang.split(...);
result = Arrays.asList(languages);
```

All you need is

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(lang.split(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because array languages" contains {"fr"," de"," gb"," nl"," se"," es"}
it contains " de" not "de". 
You can correct it in two different ways,
1: Split languages with " ," (syntax may be different).
2: compare the correct strings including space.

Answer (score 1):

You get the spaces with your split, I would use split with `\\s+` which will remove the white space for you.

```
String lang = "fr, de, gb, nl, se, es";
String[] languages = lang.split(",\\s+");
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(languages);
if (result.contains("de")) {
    System.out.println("Result contains de");
} else {
    System.out.println("Result does not contain de");
}
```

Output is

```
Result contains de
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"fr, de, gb, nl, se, es"
```

you are checking for  `de` instead of `<space>de`.

Comment: This is explanation of problem, now it is time for solution to make this answer full.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are separated with ", ".
so if you do this:

```
if (result.contains(" de")
```

it will work.

Comment: This *will* work, but a better solution would be changing the `split` itself to consume the space.

Answer (score 0):

Split the lang String after ", " or remove the spaces in the initialization

Answer (score -2):

change your string like this

```
String lang = "fr,de,gb,nl,se,es";
```

or change like @TheLostMoind said